# How is '打って' being used in this context?

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

この歌：http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEwycsmfACg

最初の歌詞はこれです：

「またビートを打ってリリック書く
だってそうじゃなきゃ俺が俺じゃない」

でも意味が分かんない。
英語で説明していい。

"(I'm) writing lyrics for another beat ...
... If I'm not, then it's not me"と思いますけど、確かめたいです。

Answer (score 5):

ここの「ビートを打つ」は「to pump beats」のような英訳が良かろうと思います。

下手ではありますが・・・ラップ風に訳してみます。

> [At it again]{また}, [writin' new lyrics]{リリック書く} [and pumpin' out beats]{ビートを打って}
>
> [I just can't stop]{だってそうじゃなきゃ}, ['cuz this who I be]{俺が俺じゃない}

「beats」と「be」とで韻を踏んでみたんだけど、どうですかね(・・?

Comment: えぇ？！あんたのラップ風は上手すぎると思います！
正体がばれた！（笑）＾＾；

説明してくれてありがとう！

Comment: いやいや、そんなf(^^;　でも解決できて良かったです。